# Problem in downloading image through urllib.request

Tags: python, urllib

I am using the below code to download image. In one system, the image is getting downloaded(Python 3.8.1) but in another system (Python 3.8.3), the image is **not getting downloaded** & it is **not giving any error also**.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/image8-2.jpg", "test.jpg")
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please notice that a downloading issue of some specific image file is **not** a `machine-learning`, `deep-learning`, or `computer-vision` issue, and it should not be tagged as such (edited).

Comment: You could keep the returned tuple `resp = urlib.request.urlretrieve(...)` and see whether the returned header has useful information.

Comment: @tdelaney In both the system, the header information is almost the same (except the instance number). It is coming something like this:

('test.jpg', <http.client.HTTPMessage at 0x16c41b6s5w0>)